# DB2 CLP - Stopped working after running db2set and db2extsec

Tags: command-line, db2

Ran the following command based on the recommendation in a document:

```
db2set -g DB2SYSTEM=%computername%
db2extsec -u %computername%\db2users -a %computername%\db2admns
```

After that DB2 CLP is not opening. I just see a windows command prompt window. How can I fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate (in the absence of any details in the question) of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48217096/why-the-command-line-of-db2-ibm-not-working

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate - In my case it is Windows 7, db2 command prompt was showing the correct prompt before I ran the db2set and db2extsec commands. If I type in the command db2 now, it just shows the windows prompt and does nothing.

Comment: Is your userid a member of either (or both) of local groups db2users, db2admns ?  Is your workstation joined to a domain ?  The more information you add to your question, the more likely you will get an answer.  Also, add the output of db2level when you edit your question.